# What is the story of Vishnu's incarnation Sisumara?

Tags: vishnu, identification-request

[This chapter](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/6/6/) of Bhagavatha Purana mention about Vishnu's incarnation, Sisumara.

> From Kṛttikā, another wife of Agni, came the son named Skanda, Kārttikeya, whose sons were headed by Viśākha. From the womb of Śarvarī, the wife of the Vasu named Doṣa, came the son named **Śiśumāra, who was an expansion of the Supreme Personality of Godhead**.

My question is, What is story of this Sisumara?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sisumara is Lord Vishnu in the form of a planetary system -

"*Lord Viṣṇu, who is the source of knowledge and transcendental bliss, has assumed the form of Śiśumāra in the seventh heaven, which is situated in the topmost level of the universe. All the other planets, beginning with the sun, exist under the shelter of this Śiśumāra planetary system.*"

Srimad Bhagavatam 5.22.17